# sql command to find average count of user visits to a website from past 6 months

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 2 columns, Date and number of visits.

i need to calculate average count difference of visits by month from past 6 months

```
Date       Number_of_Visits

2018-04-06   5
2018-02-06   6
2017-04-10   3
2017-02-10   9
```

SQL should output

```
Avg_count difference visits past 6 months
5-3=2
6-9=-3

-3+2/2=-0.5
```

sql query output should be -0.5

creating sql as below

```
With cte as (
SELECT Year(v1.date) as Year, Month(v1.date) as Month, sum(v1.visits) as SumCount 
  FROM visits_table v1 
  group by Year(v1.date), Month(v1.date)
)
```

Comment: why `5-3` and `6-9`?

Answer (score 1):

You wanted the average of the different of the same month over the years ? Year on Year comparison ?

This will gives you the result that you want `-0.5`

```
; With 
cte as 
(
    SELECT Year(v1.date) as Year, Month(v1.date) as Month, sum(v1.visits) as SumCount 
    FROM   visits_table v1 
    WHERE  v1.date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE()) -- Add here
    group by Year(v1.date), Month(v1.date)
)
SELECT  AVG (diff * 1.0)
FROM
(
    SELECT  *, diff = SumCount 
                    - LAG (SumCount) OVER (PARTITION BY Month 
                                               ORDER BY Year)
    FROM    cte
) d
```

Comment: I believe above query calculates Average difference of same month count for all years. Thank you.

Comment: How to calculate average difference of same month count  for past 6 months, do i need to add where condition

Comment: Yes. Add the `WHERE` clause to only return the required result

Comment: i ran below query shows average but if past 6 months overlaps to previous year that is if current date is 2018/03, if i run the query to find past 6 months average count difference monthly i believe i need to modify the where condition, any suggestions ?

Comment: With cte as (
SELECT Year(v1.date) as Year, Month(v1.date) as Month, sum(v1.visits) as SumCount 
  FROM [visits_table] v1 
  
  group by Year(v1.date), Month(v1.date)
)

SELECT  AVG (diff * 1.0)
FROM
(
    SELECT  *, diff = SumCount 
                    - LAG (SumCount) OVER (PARTITION BY Month 
                                               ORDER BY Year)
    FROM    cte
) d

where d.Year=Year(getdate()) and (d.Month <= Month(getdate()) -1) and (d.Month >= Month(getdate()) - 6)

Comment: add the `WHERE` to the query in the `cte` . Updated the query

Comment: adding where in the cte filters out previous year monthly visits count.

Comment: what are the date range that you want ?

Comment: from current date to past 6 months